# what do Android RatingBar attributes represent?

Tags: android, android-widget

i apologize for this question but i am having problems understanding the RatingBar attributes.

Basically, I am trying to create a rating bar with a total of 7 stars and it "jumps" by 0.5 stars each time.

The below is what i currently have. but it seems to be showing me 1/4 stars and 3/4 stars but never a proper half star.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:numStars="7"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

what is the difference between rating and numStars? I just need a simple denomination of 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so apparently my current values for attributes are correct. the reason why i am seeing 1/4 or 3/4 stars is because the width of my screen wasnt long enough. when i changed to landscape it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the doc :

```
Attribute Name  Related Method  Description
android:isIndicator setIsIndicator(boolean) Whether this rating bar is an indicator (and non-changeable by the user). 
android:numStars        The number of stars (or rating items) to show. 
android:rating      The rating to set by default. 
android:stepSize        The step size of the rating.
```

Comment: yeah i read that but whats the difference between numStars and rating? or how do i achieve my 3.5/7 stars? what i have is not showing correctly. T_T

Answer (score 0):

> 1/7=0.1428 your denomitor
>
> [Finde denomitor](http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/common-denominator.html)